# Why am I unable to specify a field to return with the projection parameter in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

The projection parameter of `db.collection.find()` determines which field to return in the matching documents and the following operation is supposed to returns all the documents from the collection and returns only the `symbol` and `timestamp` fields.

But for some reason it return all fields. What could be the reason ?

```
  collection.find({}, {
    symbol: 1, timestamp: 1}
  ).sort( { timestamp: 1 } ).toArray(function(err, docs) {

      assert.equal(err, null);
      console.log("Found the following records");
      console.log(docs);
      callback(docs);
    });
```

I'm able to filter using query operators and to sort, only have an issue with the projection. Typo is correct.

EDIT> These are my npm packages installed.

```
$ npm ls
abcdef@1.0.0 /home/abcdef
├─┬ bson-ext@2.0.0
│ ├── bindings@1.3.0
│ ├── bson@2.0.6
│ └── nan@2.10.0
└─┬ mongodb@3.0.7
  └─┬ mongodb-core@3.0.7
    ├── bson@1.0.6
    └─┬ require_optional@1.0.1
      ├── resolve-from@2.0.0
      └── semver@5.5.0
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, it works by adding a `fields{}` element inside `find()`.